# Make development on SAP Netweaver AS more comfortable?

Tags: tomcat, jakarta-ee, jboss, par, sap-enterprise-portal

I'm developing a J2EE-based web application on a SAP Netweaver Application Server. I have 2 questions:

1. I have to deploy PAR file every time I want to test my JSPDynPage or portal component on this remote server. This operation is expensive if I have a lot of deploy in a day. I want deploy SAP Portal or my component on a local Servlet Container like Tomcat or an application server like JBoss. Is it possible?
2. I'm developing on Netweaver 7.0, can I install its plugins on Eclipse 3 or use another IDE for a more pleasing experience?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One of the suggested solution is to install both the NW Developper Studio and the Java AS on the same machine (ie having a local portal). This was a recomended solution a few years ago (EP6), and is still describer in the installation manual for NWDS 7.1 SP3.

However, you'll need a powerful machine for this solution to work.

Regards